# TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

Tags: python, typeerror

I am running into the following error when I try to connect to an API using M2Crypto HTTPSConnection library using the GET method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "osg-gridadmin-cert-request", line 665, in <module>
    status = check_quota_limit(request_count)
  File "osg-gridadmin-cert-request", line 543, in check_quota_limit
    conn.request('GET', arguments['quotaurl'], headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 941, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 937, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 801, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py", line 217, in write
    return self._write_nbio(data)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/M2Crypto/SSL/Connection.py", line 202, in _write_nbio
    return m2.ssl_write_nbio(self.ssl, data)
TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

I am accessing the API using this code

```
conn = M2Crypto.httpslib.HTTPSConnection(arguments['host'],
            ssl_context=ssl_context)
        conn.request('GET', arguments['quotaurl'], headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
```

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Anyone have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the error message

```
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
```

This indicates that you are passing "headers" where you are supposed to pass "body".

So, try calling

```
conn.request('GET', arguments['quotaurl'], None, headers)
```

Comment: <pre>I tried that<br>It gives 400 in response status<br> It might mean that the server didn't understand the request or it was malformed<br>